# why sprintf using type specifier 'f' doesn't properly format number?

Tags: php, localization, number-formatting

What happened:
I set my MS Windows locale to 'Polish_Poland.1250' (using `setlocale(LC_ALL, "polish_poland")`).
Then I used `sprintf('%.2f',5.55)`, and anticipated output **5,55** but I got **5.55**.

Different things happen using **linux**. Locale is set by `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL.UTF-8')`.
Then sprintf('%.2f',5.55) outputs **5,55** (value I was expecting on MS Windows).

Please explain me this strange (erroneous?) behavior.

Edit: this is how my app sets locale

```
    if($os==='windows')
    {
        putenv('LANG=polish.UTF8');
        putenv('LANGUAGE=polish.UTF8');

        bind_textdomain_codeset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'UTF8');
        $debug = setlocale(LC_ALL, Cms_Aplikacja::$config['LC_WINDOWS']);
    }
    else if($os==='linux')
    {
        $debug = setlocale(LC_ALL, Cms_Aplikacja::$config['LC_LINUX']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`setlocale()`'s first argument should be `LC_ALL` and the second should be the wished locale.

Comment: I made mistake, writing question, of course setlocale's first argument is LC_ALL